# i want ajax response only once , currently executing same queries again i want it only once after sending and geyying ajax response

Tags: ajax

i am sending ajax req. to a php page in which i uses while loop to fetch all data , i want to reduce data by 1 and update exixting data and insert in new table , i want this operation only once but problem is that updating and inserting data more times.

```
    $("#create_button").click(function(){

             if (! confirm('Do You Want To Create Product?')) { return false;  preventDefault(); }else{
    $.ajax({
        type :'POST',
        url : 'response.php', //Here you will fetch records 
        //dataType:'json',
        data :{'select_id':select_id},
        success:function(response){
          //alert(response);





        }

    });
             }

 });
        }
```

in response.php

```
  <?php
include_once("../database/db.php");

if(isset($_POST["select_id"]))
 {
    $select_id=$_POST["select_id"];
 $get_product=$con1->query("SELECT * FROM `components` WHERE 
    FIND_IN_SET($select_id,product_id)");
    $i=1;
     while($row=$get_product->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      $component_id=$row['id'];
       $component_qty=$row['quantity_remain'];


     $sql = "UPDATE components SET quantity_remain=? WHERE id=?" ;
       $con1->prepare($sql)->execute([$component_qty - 1,$component_id]);


     $i++;
        }





            $sql = "INSERT INTO created_products (product_id) 
 VALUES (?)";
    $con1->prepare($sql)->execute([$select_id]);    
          unset($_POST["select_id"]);


}



    ?>
```

Comment: Can i have some more details? where did u put while loop?

Comment: in response.php

Comment: due to while loop i can fetch all data one by one but after fetching data i want to reduct data by 1 and update it, but the data updated any times which i dnt want

Comment: instead of getting one by one within while loop, consider fetch all data from one ajax call